# WPF Visibility attribute designer issue

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, designer, visibility

I've recently started having issues with Visibility attribute at designtime. Everything works fine at runtime but the Visibility attribute has no effect at designtime.

I've reinstalled Visual Studio and the .net framework but the issue persists.

Sample code:

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="X" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Red" />
        <TextBlock Text="Y"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

At runtime X is collapsed while at designtime it is shown.

Comment: Though a good catch, but still i doubt that this is an issue. I mean it seems a desired functionality to me.

Comment: This works normally on other machines so I'm guessing there's something wrong with this particular installation. I can work around it but it makes me worried if something else has broken too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing VS2010 SP1 fixed the issue. SP can be found at: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5

Comment: If this fixes the issue for most users I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: Fixed it for me too.  I also never knew it worked on some machines prior to SP1.

Answer (score 1):

try `Ctrl + Shift + B` after you changed code.. this maybe help you..

But i recomend you to install Microsoft Expression Blend. And make all Xaml markup, up there.

---

**Update:**

Or you can use this:

```
public class VisibilityFixer: DependencyObject
{
    public static bool GetFixDesigner(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(FixDesignerProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFixDesigner(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FixDesignerProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FixDesigner.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FixDesignerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FixDesigner", typeof(bool), typeof(VisibilityFixer),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChanged)));

    public static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = sender as FrameworkElement;

        if (obj != null)
        {
            if ((bool)(DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject)).DefaultValue)) 
            {
               if (obj.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    obj.Opacity = 0;
                    obj.Height = 0;
                    obj.Width = 0;
                } 
                else if (obj.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden)
                {
                    obj.Opacity = 0;
                }             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this..

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         Visibility="Collapsed" 
         fx:VisibilityFixer.FixDesigner="True" 
         Text="TextBlock3243" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Background="Red" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"><Run Text="TextBlock"/></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

and then use `Ctrl + Shift + B`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but neither rebuilding the project, reopening the design window or reopening the solution fixes the problem. It's not a problem of designer not being updated but the designer not applying the visibility attribute at all.

Comment: Well, i actually find that i have same issue.. but in Expression Blend everithing works fine, so think about it..

Comment: read my update.. you can always extend my code to something generic, or more usable.. i just made an example..

Comment: +1 for the effort. But Visibility works in VS on my home machine and co-workers machine. I'm guessing there's something wrong with my installation. Will check it out and report if I find something.